# Can't find the bug in my linked list code

Tags: c, linked-list

This function is supposed to load some personal information from a file and put it into a linked list, and then return a pointer tp the first element of the list. The structure used is as in the code , full name and a ID(index) for every user

```
    typedef struct Serveur
     {
      char ID[6];
      char nom[CMAX];
      char prenom[CMAX];
      struct Serveur *nxt;
     }Serveur;

Serveur *creer_liste()
  {
      return NULL;
  }

Serveur* add_server(Serveur *tete,char ID[6],char nom[CMAX],char prenom[CMAX])
  {
     Serveur* T=malloc(sizeof(Serveur));
     T->ID=ID;
     T->nom=nom;
     T->prenom=prenom;
     T->nxt=tete;
     tete=T;
     return tete;
  }

Serveur *load_servers()  //load servers list from the daba base and organise them
  {
      int c=0; char ID[6],nom[CMAX],prenom[CMAX];
      Serveur *tete;
      FILE *fichier=NULL;
      fichier=fopen("base/serveurs_liste.txt","w");
      if(fichier==NULL)
        return NULL;
      else
       {
         rewind(fichier);
         c=fgetc(fichier);
         if(c==EOF)
            return NULL;
         else
          {
            rewind(fichier);
            while(!feof(fichier))
              {
                do{c=fgetc(fichier);}
                while(c!='\n');
                fscanf(fichier,"%s %s %s",ID,nom,prenom);
                tete=add_server(tete,ID,nom,prenom)
              }
          }
        }
      return tete;
  }
```

but I face this error, every thing seems to me be logic, I really can't find what is wrong there so please if anyone can figure out what is going bad there

Comment: Did you use a debugger?  Which one? What did you learn from it? _(why didn't you??)_

Comment: Hello there. Pardon my sarcasm, but the fact is machine based debuggers are often more useful than human debuggers. :-)

Comment: `T->ID=ID;` --> `strcpy(T->ID, ID);`

Comment: `fichier=fopen("base/serveurs_liste.txt","w");` : `w` --> `r` then need `fclose(fichier);`

Comment: "but I face this error".  Which error would that be?

Comment: `Serveur *tete;` at `load_servers`,  --> `Serveur *tete=NULL;`

Comment: The term is "linked list", not "chained list". I've updated the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the wrong value from `add_server`. You should instead return the newly allocated `T`:

```
Serveur* add_server(Serveur *tete,char ID[6],char nom[CMAX],char prenom[CMAX])
  {
     Serveur* T=malloc(sizeof(Serveur));
     T->ID=ID;
     T->nom=nom;
     T->prenom=prenom;
     T->nxt=tete;
     return T;
  }
```